# Teamcity is not copying all the folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, teamcity, publishing

I've now setup a MSBuild script to create the folders and files I need in the right structure for my MVC project. I'm then setting Teamcity up to look at the folder with only the files I want to have and copy that to the artifacts folder. So far, so good!
However, There is a few folders in the structure that are empty, and Teamcity does not copy these folder, even if I've set it up to copy the mainfolder and everything in it.

Is there a way to force Teamcity to copy everything - and by that I mean EVERYTHING in my folder, or does it simply not work?

Teamcity Artifact path settings:

```
Website => Release
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We manage to work around this and skip the empty folders. Therefore this was no longer an issue. However, still don't know how to copy empty folders. My understanding from doing research for a long while now is that it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer in this post : [How do I exclude the contents of a directory but not the directory itself in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804383/how-do-i-exclude-the-contents-of-a-directory-but-not-the-directory-itself-in-msbu/3805180#3805180)

It's not Teamcity but still MsBuild. The problem is that msbuild's include does not include empty directories...

Comment: The thing is, as I said, that I already have a MSBuild script setting up the whole structure with directories and files as I want it. In order to make it available to the user to download it straight from the web interface I need to set up Teamcity to point at that folder. That's when I get the issue. It's now skipping all the empty folders.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood you.